# Equality of Expectations

Tags: probability

Is the following equality right? Let $(B^H)$ be the fBM
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k\left(B^H_{\frac{k}{c_n}}-B^H_{\frac{k-1}{c_n}}\right)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k\left(B^H_{\frac{x+k}{c_n}}-B^H_{\frac{x+k-1}{c_n}}\right)\right]
=c_n^{-2H}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k_1,k_2=1}^n\alpha_{k_1}\alpha_{k_2}X_{k_1}X_{k_2}\right]
$$
Where $c_n>n$ is integer valued and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and >0 and $(X_\ell)_{\ell\geq 0}$ is the fractional Gaussian noise.

Comment: Independently of $x$?

Comment: by stationarity of increments?

Comment: I mean, the LHS seems to depend on $x$, not the RHS, hence are you sure this is the statement you want to prove?

Comment: I want to calculate the LHS. I thought, that it does not depent on on $x$ because of stationarity.

Comment: can anyone give me a feedback?Again I want to calculate the LHS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $(B^{H}_{x+k}-B^{H}_{x+k-1})\overset{d}{=}(B^{H}_{k}-B^{H}_{k-1})$ no $x$ appears on the RHS. Is there a fundamental mistake?

Comment: Yes. Which is that one should multiply each of these by the increments in the first sum--and then the dependence structure enters the scene.

Comment: Let $X_{k_{1}}:=B^{H}_{k_{1}}-B^{H}_{k_{1}-1}$ and $Y_{k_{2}}:=B^{H}_{x+k_{2}}-B^{H}_{x+k_{2}-1}$. So the LHS is $\sum_{k_{1},k_{2}=1}^{n}\alpha_{k_{1}}\alpha_{k_{2}}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k_{1}}Y_{k_{2}}\right]$ Using the correlation structure of the fBM we get: $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{k_{1}}Y_{k_{2}}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\gamma(k_{1},x+k_{2})-\frac{1}{2}\gamma(k_{1},x+k_{2}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\gamma(k_{1}-1,x+k_{2})+\frac{1}{2}\gamma(k_{1}-1,x+k_{2}-1)$ where $\gamma(s,t)=\mathbb{E}\left[B^{H}_{s}B^{H}_{t}\right]$ Is it possible to do further simplifications?

Comment: Yes. Plug in $\gamma$.

Comment: Ok, but after I have plugged in $\gamma$ in the sum, there is no way to simplify the sum?
Iam sorry because of the typos in my above comment, but I have tried to fix them $\infty$ many times, but it still does not work.

Comment: If you want to see if some cancellations occur, write down the sum and check. For that, you should write down explicitly $\gamma$.